# String reverse operation

Tags: scheme

I want to write string reverse function without using either append or reverse functions.

I wrote the code as follows:

```
> (define rdc(lambda (ls)
                   (cond((null? ls) '())
                        (else (cons (rdc (cdr ls)) (car ls))))))
```

The output for this code is as follows:

```
Input: > (rdc '(a b c))
Output: (((() . c) . b) . a)
```

But I want output in the form of (c b a). I'm using DrScheme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is performing the `cons` operation in the wrong order, that's why the result is *not* a well-formed list.

The correct answer is simple using an accumulator for storing the answer - with the nice side effect that this is a tail-recursive solution:

```
(define (rdc lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))))
```

The previous procedure uses a named let for implementing the recursion. Alternatively, you could use an inner helper procedure, this version is completely equivalent:

```
(define (rdc lst)
  (define (loop lst acc)
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))
  (loop lst '()))
```

Either way, this works:

```
(rdc '(a b c))
> '(c b a)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one notorious way to do this, which many people discover by accident:

```
(fold cons '() '(a b c d))
```

If this is coursework then that probably isn't acceptable but it's useful to understand

Comment: I completed the work with append operation but I'm finding a way if it is possible to work out only using cons, car and cdr

Comment: It's possible to implement append using only cons, car and cdr, so the answer is yes.

Comment: so what is the error in my code written in the question? what are the modifications that I should do for that?

Answer (score -1):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder ob = new StringBuilder("welcome");// original string
        StringBuilder ot = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = ob.Length - 1; i > -1;i-- )
        {
            ot.Append(ob[i]);//that object contain reverse string.
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ot);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```